# How to combine two curves with different range into one plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to put my two subplots into one plot without changing their shape. They have a very different y range.

[image]

What I want to get is something like the following figure

[image]

But I don't know how to get that figure. I've tried using twin axes but it does not give me a very good result.

Here is some toy data to use:

```
t = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
line1 = np.sin(t)
line2 = 10*np.sin(t)
```

Comment: What's wrong with the twin axes solution? It's the standard solution to this problem, so to provide an alternative that works around the problems you're finding with the standard solution, it would be helpful to know what those problems are.

Comment: @yifei-xiao With twin axes you have to modify the ylims to position the plots.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should be pretty close:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
t = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
line1 = np.sin(t)
line2 = 10 * np.sin(t)

fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 1, sharex=True)
fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=0)
axs[0].spines['bottom'].set_visible(False)
axs[1].spines['top'].set_visible(False)
axs[0].plot(t, line1)
axs[1].plot(t, line2)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That's what I'm looking for.