# How to superimpose/shift axes on a graph?

Tags: python, matplotlib, physics

I would like my y-axis to be superimposed/shifted as it is in this image:

[image]

Here is the graph that I have created using python with the code shown below:

[image]

There is only one origin on the graph I produced. I would like there to be at least three so that the functions with the smaller amplitudes are more visible/ easier to read.

What functions can I use to achieve this?

Thank you!

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math 


def initial(): 
    #obtain inital parameters
    dt = .04
    g = 9.8
    l = 9.8
    q = 0.5
    f_d = 1.2 #driving force
    frequency = 0.667 #frequency of driving force
    theta_start = 0.2
    omega_start = 0
    time_stop = 60
    return dt, g, l, q, frequency, theta_start, omega_start, time_stop

def rk_2(dt, g, l, q, frequency, theta_start, omega_start, time_stop): 
    #create arrays for theta and omega, calculate omega and theta using rk2 method
    forces = [0, 0.5, 1.2]


    j = 0
    while j < 3:
        f_d = forces[j]
        theta = [] 
        omega = []
        time = [np.array([0])]
        theta = np.append(theta, theta_start)
        omega = np.append(omega, omega_start)
        i = 0
        while time[i] < time_stop:
            #if theta[i] not in range(-3.14,3.14)
            theta_prime = theta[i] + 0.5*omega[i]*dt
            omega_prime = omega[i] + 0.5*((-g/l)*math.sin(theta[i]) - q*omega[i] + f_d*math.sin(frequency*time[i]))*dt
            time_prime = time[i] + 0.5*dt

            theta_new = theta[i] + omega_prime*dt
            omega_new = omega[i] + ((-g/l)*math.sin(theta_prime) - q*omega[i] + f_d*math.sin(frequency*time_prime))*dt
            time_new = time[i] + dt

            theta = np.append(theta, theta_new)
            omega = np.append(omega, omega_new)
            time = np.append(time, time_new)
            i = i + 1
        plt.plot(time, theta)
        j = j+1
    plt.plot(time, theta)
    plt.xlabel('Time [s]')
    plt.ylabel('Angle [rad]')
    plt.show()

    return theta, omega, time

def main():
    dt, g, l, q, frequency, theta_start, omega_start, time_stop = initial()
    theta, omega, time = rk_2(dt, g, l, q, frequency, theta_start, omega_start, time_stop)
    #plot(theta, omega, time)

main()
```

Comment: There's not an easy way to do this exact plot in matplotlib. There's an example in a recent question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61490753/how-to-combine-two-curves-with-different-range-into-one-plot) but imho, it's not a great answer since the y tick spacing is not going to be the same for the two plots (as it is for the plot you show, which is an important feature of the way it's drawn). But, in my opinion, it's better to just show independent axes, if you want independent axes, like [this](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/subplots_demo.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer referenced in [@tom10](https://stackoverflow.com/users/102302/tom10)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61648477/how-to-superimpose-shift-axes-on-a-graph#comment109049370_61648477) can be modified to ensure the tick spacing is consistent across all subplots, even when the height of the subplots is different, by explicitly setting the tick locations (and labels) as well as the limits for each subplot:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math 

ratios = [5, 5, 7]
lim = [[-0.3, 0.3], [-1, 1], [-12,4]]
labels = [['' if (e != (ratios[j] - 1) / 2) else 0 
           for e in range(ratios[j]-1)]+[lim[j][1]] for j in range(len(ratios))]
fig, axs = plt.subplots(3, 1, sharex=True, gridspec_kw={'height_ratios': ratios})
def initial(): 
    #obtain inital parameters
    dt = .04
    g = 9.8
    l = 9.8
    q = 0.5
    f_d = 1.2 #driving force
    frequency = 0.667 #frequency of driving force
    theta_start = 0.2
    omega_start = 0
    time_stop = 60
    return dt, g, l, q, frequency, theta_start, omega_start, time_stop

def rk_2(dt, g, l, q, frequency, theta_start, omega_start, time_stop): 
    forces = [0, 0.5, 1.2]

    for j in range(3):
        f_d = forces[j]
        theta = [] 
        omega = []
        time = [np.array([0])]
        theta = np.append(theta, theta_start)
        omega = np.append(omega, omega_start)
        i = 0
        while time[i] < time_stop:
            theta_prime = theta[i] + 0.5*omega[i]*dt
            omega_prime = omega[i] + 0.5*((-g/l)*math.sin(theta[i]) - q*omega[i] + 
                                          f_d*math.sin(frequency*time[i]))*dt
            time_prime = time[i] + 0.5*dt

            theta_new = theta[i] + omega_prime*dt
            omega_new = omega[i] + ((-g/l)*math.sin(theta_prime) - q*omega[i] + 
                                    f_d*math.sin(frequency*time_prime))*dt
            time_new = time[i] + dt

            theta = np.append(theta, theta_new)
            omega = np.append(omega, omega_new)
            time = np.append(time, time_new)
            i = i + 1
        axs[j].plot(time, theta)
        if j != 0: axs[j].spines['top'].set_visible(False)
        if j != 2: 
            axs[j].spines['bottom'].set_visible(False)
            axs[j].tick_params(bottom=False)
        axs[j].tick_params(axis='y', direction='in')
        axs[j].set_ylim(lim[j])
        axs[j].set_yticks(np.linspace(lim[j][0], lim[j][1], ratios[j]))
        axs[j].set_yticklabels(labels[j])
    plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0)
    plt.figtext(0.08, 0.5, 'Angle [rad]', rotation = 90, ha='center', va='center')
    plt.xlabel('Time [s]')
    plt.show()

    return theta, omega, time

def main():
    dt, g, l, q, frequency, theta_start, omega_start, time_stop = initial()
    theta, omega, time = rk_2(dt, g, l, q, frequency, theta_start, omega_start, time_stop)

main()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help! This is very insightful

Comment: @choudrie Glad I could help, you should consider [accepting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) this if you feel it appropriately answered your question - that way the question is marked as such for future users.